# "context" cannot be constructed using c++ API in latest version of z3 (4.3.2)

Tags: c++, api, z3

My problem is as followed,

Environment: 64 bit windows 7, vs 2010, z3-4.3.2

First, compiled Z3 from source(download from z3 homepage ), this step is ok and without any mistake (from the command window);

Second, tested the c++ example under the “src/example”, first, test function find_model_example1(), compile, link, this is no warning, and error. However, got stuck when run. Then, after I debug step by step, stuck at the second statement, “context c”;

```
1, std::cout << "find_model_example1\n";
2, context c;
3, expr x = c.int_const("x");
```

Keep going with F11 at this statement, it stuck at  function “reinterpret_cast” , line 424 in api_context.cpp, keep going with F11, in the constructor of “context” :“context(config_params *, bool)”, function “m_replay_stack” will call function “copy_core”(vector.h), which triggered 0xC00000005 error.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem; does it still exist? If so, could you try building the source from the unstable branch so we can see whether this problem still exists in the latest version?

Comment: It still exist. The latest testing is with vs2012, z3-4.3.2 master(release ,-staticlib), and unstable(release, -staticlib?(cannot remember)),problem as followed :      Unhandled exception at 0x1006CE75(libz3.dll)(for both    master and unstable version)  in xx.exe: 0XC0000005 : Access violation reading location 0Xccccccc8.(location as before)..
     Master( release, not -staticlib) got the same problem with another xxxxx.dll instead  of libz3.dll.   

Besides, z3-4.3.2 works well at Ubuntu 12.04.64 from my Virtualbox. And Z3-4.3.1 works well with vs2012/2010/2008.(I prefer z3-4.3.2 than 4.3.1)

Comment: Sometimes users run into issues when they build on top of old code.

Comment: Yes, make sure you're building from scratch like Nikolaj said. Our nightly unstable binaries are also compiled with VS2010 and we haven't seen any problems of that sort before.

Comment: ok! I will try again, Thanks Nikolaj, and Christoph.

Comment: @NikolajBjorner, I noticed there are libz3.lib and z3.lib under build directory, and several libs under sub-directory (api.lib is under api), it got a same crash by adding libz3.lib,  and both libz3.lib and z3.lib , linking errors by adding z3.lib, I wondered, should I add the all libs under the build directory and sub-directory? (Z3 was compiled with default configuration)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved at this point.